# How to end a while loop using break in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, global-variables, break

i wrote here a loop which asks the user if he want to repeat a block of instructions.
And wanted to give the user three tries to choose what he wants (Yes / No) if he doesn't the loop end.
This is my code:

```
# Ask for repeating
i = 0
def question():
    global i
    while True:
        print("Give another try?")
        answer = input("(Y/N): ")
        answer = answer.upper()
        if answer == 'Y':
            main()
        elif answer == 'N':
            print("Thank you for participating")
            break # here it works when 'n' is typed
        else: # i count how much the while loop id repeated
            if (i < 2):
                i += 1
                question()
            else: # else is executed when i == 2
                print("don't Play with us!!")
                break # here it doesn't work.
```

I want help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = True
i = 0
def question():
    # Ask for repeating
    global i
    global x
    while x is True:
        print("Give another try?")
        answer ='a'
        answer = answer.upper()
        if answer == 'Y':
            pass
        elif answer == 'N':
            print("Thank you for participating")
            break  # here it works when 'n' is typed
        else:  # i count how much the while loop id repeated
            if (i < 2):
                i += 1
                question()
            else:  # else is executed when i == 2
                print("don't Play with us!!")
                x = False  # here it doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another break outside the last else block. Your code should be

```
i = 0
def question():
    global i
    while True:
        print("Give another try?")
        answer = input("(Y/N): ")
        answer = answer.upper()
        if answer == 'Y':
            main()
        elif answer == 'N':
            print("Thank you for participating")
            break # here it works when 'n' is typed
        else: # i count how much the while loop id repeated
            if (i < 2):
                i += 1
                question()
            else: # else is executed when i == 2
                print("don't Play with us!!")
                break # here it doesn't work.
            break
```

Comment: ohh and this is my fault: break should be outside the second 'else'.